# I Have a Triban RC 100 (Small, Women's bike) I am upgrading the cransket to a Shimano 105, do I need to upgrade the entire transmission too?

Tags: crankset, cassette, derailleur-rear, derailleur-front, transmission

I have a Triban RC 100 women's road bike and I bent the stock cransket in a crash so I am looking to upgrade to something better. I was thinking of upgrading the cransket to a Shimano Sora but would that also require me to upgrade the rear derailleur and the cassette?

Comment: Are you only changing the chainring or also the crank arm ?

Comment: A quick web search shows that the Triban RC100 has a single front chainring, not a dual. If that is correct, it will play a big part in what choices you have if you are not going to update a bunch of components.

Comment: Could also good to detail the components of the bike you have. There are many differences between years and countries (for instance, the RC100 sold in Europe has a thumb-shifter, the one in India an integrated lever for shifter and brake). Also, the title says 105, the question says Sora. I would be could to indicate which version. Previous versions were using freewheels, current ones have cassettes. All of this will impact the answer.

Comment: If you want a better crankset, the best choice is probably to take something a single chainring crankset from the new Shimano CUES range. The inside width of 7-speed chains is only 0.2mm wider than the inside width of 11-speed chains, that wouldn't be perfect, but mitigated by the fact that single chainrings don't need to derail. Just keep in mind that this range is designed for MTB bottom brackets, that you can fit on road bikes but you'll need to add 2 2.5mm spacers when mounting them.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the upgrade? There may be better ways to achieve your real goal. Wjat exact version of Triban RC 100 do you have? If you cannot identify the components, you can show a photo.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at a couple of iterations of your Triban RC 100.  [This version seems to have MicroShift components](https://99spokes.com/bikes/triban/2020/rc100-road-bike), where as in this [**RoadCC** review of the Triban RC 100](https://road.cc/content/review/decathlon-btwin-triban-100-road-bike-250460), the bike sports a Shimano 7 speed thumb shifter and Shimano Tourney derailleur.  I'll get to the significance of this in relation to your crankset choice in a moment.

What is common among the RC 100 iterations I've come across via Google search--at least the models since 2021--is they all featured single chainring cranksets (AKA 1x, "one-by"). So the first problem with the Sora crankset choice is that the Sora is only offered in two (2x) or three (3x) chainring set-ups.  As you do not currently have a front derailleur or front shifter, these too would have to be purchased and installed to run any multi-ring crankset.

To directly answer your question, yes, you will have to essentially obtain a nearly entirely different drive train to accompany a Sora crankset. Note there are other considerations such as the fact Shimano Sora is a 9 speed (rear) system and your current set up is 7 speed.

Shimano's gravel bike section does offer 1x cranksets such as the FC-RX600-1 which would work with your bike frame. Additional drivetrain parts would be required for this particular crankset as well because it's designed for 11 rear speeds.

Comment: Little correction: GRX is not a [Linkglide groupset](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/91139/what-is-linkglide-cues-and-how-do-they-differ-from-existing-standards). They can use the same chains, but that's about it. GRX is a proper 11-speed road groupset.

Comment: @Renaud Yes. I misinterpreted the [Shimano specs page for that particular crankset](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/Gravel/Crankset). For the chain it said "Linkglide, HG-11 speed" and means that either chain would be compatible.

Comment: indeed, every 11-speed component is compatible with Linkglide chains, which makes it confusing.