# SRAM 1:1 shifter + Shimano 11 speed MTB RD

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, derailleur, shifter, sram

I'm planning my next bike build with an 11-50 cassette but I don't want more than 10 gears for personal preferences. I've seen Chinese-brand drivetrains (LTWOO) that can do this but I want something a little more robust.

I figured from looking up on articles and forums that a 10 speed 1:1 SRAM shifter could work with Deore RD-M5100-SGS but I'm not very sure. Are these compatible?

Comment: If you are OK with 11-48, you have two options that work "within specs": Shimano CUES U6000 (durable range of Shimano, [10-speed but technically 11-speed](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/91139/what-is-linkglide-cues-and-how-do-they-differ-from-existing-standards)) and Microshift Advent X.